# SetInterval, ClearInterval, Slideshow wont work

Tags: javascript, class, setinterval, clearinterval

I tried, I read a lot of stackoverflows, and, I give up.
Here is my code. It is a simple slideshow where slides are the changing images and pagination is the dots which show the number of image displaying.

For some reason the images(slides) change but the selected dots dont(it shows as if its always on first). the console log returns only the first function run
:

```
first
0
0
1
2
3
```

For some reason, when calling nosotros.setSlides(3) it takes to the correct slideshow and it selects the correct pagination-dot but setInterval never stops, the pagination-dot will not move again and the slides will jump to the last next position (if i was on slide 0 and clicked on 3 i would go to 3 and then to 1).

```
class Slides {
    slideIndex;
    interval;

    slides;
    pagination;

constructor() {
  this.slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  this.pagination = document.getElementsByClassName("pagination-dot");
  this.setSlides();
}

    setSlides(x = -1){ 
      if(x == -1){
        console.log('first');
        this.slideIndex = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval( this.showSlides(), 5000 );
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.slideIndex = x;
        this.interval = setInterval( this.showSlides(), 5000);
      }
    }

    showSlides(){
      console.log(this.slideIndex);

      this.slideIndex < 0 ? this.slideIndex = 0 : 0;
      this.slideIndex >= this.slides.length ? this.slideIndex = 0 : 0;

      for( let i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++){
        if( i != this.slideIndex ){
          this.slides[i].classList.add('opacity-0'); 
          this.slides[i].classList.remove('opacity-1');
          if( this.pagination[i].classList.contains('selected') ){
            this.pagination[i].classList.remove('selected');
          }
          console.log(i);
        } else { 
          console.log(i);
          this.slides[i].classList.add('opacity-1');       
          this.slides[i].classList.remove('opacity-0');
          if(!this.pagination[i].classList.contains('selected')){
            this.pagination[i].classList.add('selected');
          }
          
        } 
      }
      
      this.slideIndex++;
    };

}

let nosotros = new Slides();
```

What am I failing to realize?

Comment: You are executing the function, not assigning it.

Comment: Doing:`setInterval( ()=>{ this.showSlides(); }, 5000 );` instead of `setInterval( this.showSlides(), 5000 );` makes it so that pagination starts on the second run but calling `nosotros.setSildes(3)`  now functions weirder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the interval. You need to assign the function.

```
setSlides(x = -1){ 
  if (this.interval) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  this.slideIndex = x == -1 ? 0 : x;
  this.interval = setInterval( () => this.showSlides(), 5000 );
  // this.interval = setInterval(this.showSlides.bind(this), 5000 );
}
```

Comment: It pointed me in the right direction. The biggest issue was i had some code in another file messing the code.